# How to set hight programmatically of ListView in ScrollView where row contains ExpandableTextView with hight wrap_content

Tags: android, listview

In row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
    <com.sample.utils.ExpandableTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_item_treatment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:minLines="2"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="Test treatments"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

For calculating listview hight programeticaly in Activity Class:

```
public void setListViewHeightBasedOnRow(ListView listView) {
    if (listView == null) {
        return;
    }
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        // pre-condition
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = listView.getPaddingTop() + listView.getPaddingBottom();
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        if (listItem instanceof ViewGroup) {
            listItem.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

I am using ListView in between ScrollView so i have to set hight programmatically of ListView for full activity scrolling.
But when the ExpandableTextView of row is expand then lower row are goes to hidden.
how to calculate and set the ListView hight in ExpandableTextView is in expand state?

Comment: listview has it's own scroll thus it coincides with scrollview scrolling behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [ScrollView | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html):

> **You should NEVER use a ScrollView with a ListView**, because ListView takes care of its own vertical scrolling. Most importantly, doing this defeats all of the important optimizations in ListView for dealing with large lists, since it effectively forces the ListView to display its entire list of items to fill up the infinite container supplied by ScrollView.

Comment: Well you can't and shouldn't do it by combining ListView and Scrollview, those are simply made to NOT work with one another. You can't just use elements that are not compatible because you want so.